# Datastax Kafka Connector Unable To Parse Json Topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, cassandra, datastax, apache-kafka-connect

I have a producer class sends to a topic using custom JsonSerializer from [Github](https://github.com/bijukunjummen/raw-kafka-producer-consumer)

```
public class JsonSerializer<T> implements Serializer<T> {
    ...
    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, T data) {
        try {
            return this.objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(data);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new SerializationException(e);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

And I am running Datastax Kafka Connector using these configuration:

```
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
```

I got these error while the connector trying to consume topic:

```
[2020-01-12 13:57:53,324] WARN Error inserting/updating row for Kafka record SinkRecord{kafkaOffset=416, timestampType=CreateTime} ConnectRecord{topic='test-3', kafkaPartition=17, key=null, keySchema=Schema{STRING}, value={}, valueSchema=null, timestamp=1578811437723, headers=ConnectHeaders(headers=)}: Primary key column(s) mmsi, ts cannot be left unmapped. Check that your mapping setting matches your dataset contents. (com.datastax.kafkaconnector.DseSinkTask:286)
```

From that error, I am thinking Connector unable to retrieve Json data. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I tried Kafka JsonSerializer.

I tried StringSerializer, as connector said it is supported also.

I found that some data actually written to database, but it is always relative small number compared to total data sent by kafka topic. About 5 to 10 data.

I tried to keep connector running, and I found after it failed wrote, it will not write anymore.

Comment: what is your mapping in the connector config, and what is the database schema?

Comment: [Apache Kafka already has a JSON Serializer](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/json/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/json/JsonSerializer.java)

Comment: Accoring to the error, you had no value to write to the database `value={}, valueSchema=null`

Comment: @cricket_007 After some research, I tried using kafka jsonserializer. And another error happenned. I'll update here once I got my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is configuration related problem. As I mentioned in update, it never wrote data anymore in case of error.

It is because Datastax have configuration `ignoreErrors` those have default value `false`. It means if Connector found an error in a message, it will retry it indefinitely. I set it to true, and problem solved.